# How to find which site ids I have in Django Admin panel sites

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I have deleted my previous site xxx.xxx.com and added a new site xx1.xxx.com. So then in the settings.py I have configured the site id to 2 and, yet it's not giving me the **django.contrib.sites.models.Site.DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.** error. How can I check the exact site ids I have right now with the shell. Because my admin panel is not loading too.

I am pretty new to django. So apologies if this is a very basic one to ask.

I tried to change the site id from 1 to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve your sites with the import

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
sites = Site.objects.all()
for site in sites:
    print(site.id)
```

And ensure that you have correctly updated the SITE_ID setting in your settings.py file to match the ID of the new site.